# How to separate rows by type from CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is how my CSV looks like right now but with a lot more rows with various types, monitors and names.

[image]

I would like to organize the rows up by the Name column type. All the data for each column should be remained but needs to be organized by the Name type.

The problem right now is that there are more website names in column C but because of the locations under the website name, it's not matched with the rows from column A and B.
How can I fix this using python?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: When you're looping over the rows, check if the current row has the same type and monitor as the previous row. If it does, leave those columns blank in your output.

Comment: @Barmar that won't catch the change from amazon.com to windows.com

Comment: Would you be open to using a library like pandas?

Comment: This looks like it may be both comma and tab delimited. Splitting on both may shift the locations into their own column.

Comment: @Kurt Good catch. I don't see a way to do that -- how can you tell which values in the `Name` column are supposed to start a new group?

Comment: would have to check for domain name pattern, or possibly leading spaces if the locations are all indented like that

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.read_csv("<file-name>")
code = df.Name.str.startswith("location")
pd.merge(df[~code].reset_index(), df[code].reset_index()[["index","Name"]], how="outer").fillna("").sort_values("index").set_index("index").to_csv("<file-name>", index=False)
```